# Raster calculation with string in modeler

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, qgis-modeler

In my model I have one raster file and also a string input (factor for further calculation). I tried to use the grass r.mapcalculator where I can find the raster and also the string input. I tried to calculate the following: `string + A` without success. I also tried `'string'+A` or `"string"+A`. Is it possible to solve this issue?

Comment: Seems that you need to explicitly modify string to float or integer `float("string")`. If you will explain how your 'string' is obtained and if it is a result of another Processing script I could help you with modification of that script or creating new one for the string conversion. For instance create following Python script (replace `\n` with a new line) `##input=string 0 \n  ##num=output number \n num = float(input)` and add it to your model to convert string to float.